# Localstorage can't generate data Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, local-storage

I want to generate new `div` element with some information from `input`, but it is not working correctly. I have a big problem with saving and receiving data from `localstorage`. I spent two days researching the issue. Would you be so kind to tell me where are the problems?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v5r653nd/1/

```
var nameaaaa = document.getElementById("nameOfbook");
var author = document.getElementById("nameOfauthor");
var year = document.getElementById("year");

function makeJob() {
  testObjects.push({
        name: nameaaaa.value,
        author: author.value,
        year: year.value
    })

localStorage.setItem('testObjects', JSON.stringify(testObjects));
```

Comment: Does the error is that it displays undefined for the book name? Or what error are you talking about

Comment: If so, you will be able to find the fix by stepping through your code in `makeJob`

Comment: @Frankusky No, it is add data to the localstorage, and after add the needed text to the div element in body. But when I try to create new infoby using input,  localstorage was rewrriten... And the same div(with info from localstorage) on the page - recieve new information from the input, when I expect new div with new info.

Comment: @Nazariy I still dont understand. In your jsfiddle it adds correctly the information, and creates correctly a new div with the new info

Comment: Oh, does it is after a refresh?

Comment: @Frankusky When I added the same div to the document several times - it works (even after refresh), but when I try to create a new one with info from input - it rewrrite prefious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly the problem, you are overwritting the localstorage since at start of the script you declare that testObject is an empty array and later you work over it and replace your localstorage with that values.

So you should retrieve the localstorage value first and store it in that variable:

```
var testObjects = localStorage.getItem("testObjects") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("testObjects")) : [];
```

[JSFiddler Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v5r653nd/2/)